# Crosswalk WebSql Limits?

Tags: web-sql, crosswalk-runtime

My cordova app currently has ~60,000 data points in PouchDB (and growing).

When using Cordova's default webkit Websql adapter it stops accepting any more writes after 50MB (known limit). The work around was to use the Cordova Sqlite plugin, which worked great until I hit around 40,000 data points. After that  anytime I tried to use PouchDB's syncing, the databases just stop responding.

( Side track: Interestingly, replicating to a remote database is fine, but the moment I tried to then replicate from the remote server, the SQLite database just stops responding all together.)

Next solution: Remove SQLite, install Crosswalk.  Now my 60,000 records work fine - and is weighing in around 59MB.

Does anyone know what the actual limit for a Crosswalk Websql Database?